# best practice to implement a multi step data validation .NET Web MVC 4 Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Which is the best practice to implement a multi step data validation in a .NET Web MVC 4 Application?
Step 1

```
<input type="email" name="email"/>
```

In the controller I check with a RegExp the validity of the email and redirect to step 2

Step 2

```
<input type="hidden" name="email"/>
<input type="password" name="pwd"/>
<input type="password" name="confirmpwd"/>
```

In the controller I check the validity of the passwords and create an user

If someone change the email in the input hidden can register an account with a not valid email.
So I can Save the email in the Session? 
Or should I encrypt with a 2 way encription the email and pass it to the form as hidden?
Revalidate the email? And in the case of big number of data?
Which is the best practice?

Comment: Why two separate steps?

Comment: Off-topic, but important. If you validate some data (email in given example) and put it in hidden field, you still need to validate it on the second step before using, because client can simply change hidden input field. To avoid this you could put submitted and validated data in session to keep persistence.

Comment: This is a banal example. There are situations that require a multi step validation. (Long forms with hundreds of fields for example insurance's web portal form)

Comment: @whiteproud - The details of the problem dictate the solution.  For example, if a user is filling out a long form with multiple pages, you might want to save their progress so that even if they log out and back in, they can continue where they left off.  In that case, you would probably use a database instead of hidden variables or session.  Please post your real use case.

Comment: In my real case In the step 1 the user can inser a personal code. If this personal code exists in my DB, He can proceed with the registration in the step 2 using the Personal code as reference for the new account.

Comment: In that case, I would treat the first step the same as logging into the site.  Once the user enters that personal code, you know who they are, and want to remember that until they log out.  So I would use the session.

Comment: And if after the first step completed by user X, another user Y copyes the cookies of the user X and register his (user Y) data with the personal code of user X? Is possible?

Comment: Well, if you sent personal code XYZ to person A, and some time later someone enters personal code XYZ into your website, how do you know that person is person A?  We don't know anything about how you plan on doing user authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly from a best practice perspective you cannot rely on use input, which includes hidden form fields. You could store the email in session, however this has implications if the server crashes, or if the server is on a farm? I would suggest storing the email in a transactional DB so it can later be retrieved.

As far as validation you should use the regex data annotation on your view model for email and if you have minimum requirements for password strength. You can also use data annotation to validate the confirm password matches the password. Finally check Model.IsValid on your controller for the best results.